# pyinstaller 3.3 and visual c++ 2015 redistributable into standalone exe (embedding)

Tags: python, visual-c++, pyinstaller

Ist there a possibility to embed Visual C++ 2015 redistributable into pyinstaller? Or: How to make pyinstaller created standalone exe work with Fresh Windows 10 install by embedding vidual 2015 redistributable DLLs.